# How to put this.props data into headerRight selector?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I use `react-redux` to get my `FlatList` data and custom my header with `react-navigation`.

I want to add a selector in `headerRight`, my problem is I have no idea how to add the data into my headerRight.

Here is my header setting.

```
const data = [
  { key: 0, section: true, label: 'Title' },
  { key: 1, label: 'Red Apples' },
  { key: 2, label: 'Cherries' },
  { key: 3, label: 'Cranberries', accessibilityLabel: 'Tap here for cranberries' },
  { key: 4, label: 'Vegetable', customKey: 'Not a fruit' }
];

class MovieTimeList extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `${navigation.state.params.theaterCn}`,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#81A3A7', 
      elevation: null,
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: '300',
      fontFamily: 'FFF Tusj',
      fontSize: 18
    },
    headerRight:
      <ModalSelector
        data={data}
        initValue="Title"
        onChange={(option)=>{ alert(`${option.label} (${option.key}) nom nom nom`) }}
      />,
  });
```

Here is my react-redux `mapStateToProps` function that action is call an API to get the data:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const timeList = state.listType.timeList;

  return { timeList };
};
```

I can show the `movieData` in `FlatList` from react-redux:

```
  render() {
    const movieData = this.props.timeList;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={movieData}
          renderItem={this.renderRow}
          horizontal={false}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}        
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I have no idea how to let the const `movieData` into my `headerRight` selector.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to retrieve the data in a container-level component and pass it down to the sub-components where your headerRight component sits.

Comment: Thanks for reply, what do you mean `container-level component ` and `sub-components` and how to connect with it ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set param and then use it in your header like this

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProp){

   if(!isFetching && listNotUpdated){
      this.props.navigation.setParams({ movieList: nextProp.timeList})
   }
 }
```

then get it in the header like this

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { state } = navigation
    const { movieList }= navigation.state.params
  return {
    title: 'Your Title',
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        title={'Button1'}
        onPress={() => {
          // do something
        }}
      />
    ),
  }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for reply. `componentDidMount()` trigger once and my `this.props.timeList` is still empty.  So I try use it in `componentWillReceiveProps` but it calls a lots of times if I use `this.props.navigation.setParams({ movieList: this.props.timeList})` and then the app crash.   Any idea ?

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is called each time when props are updated, you need to put some condition so it wont update multiple times and trigger an infinite loop like 
if(!isFetching && listNotUpdated) { //do something }

Comment: Yes, I try `    if (!this.props.navigation.state.params.movieList) {
      console.log('run !');
      this.props.navigation.setParams({ movieList: nextProps.timeList });
    }` and it is working now, Thanks @Hasider ! Helps me a lots.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this code is 100% correct, basically, you can do it by connecting ur reducer to your MovieTimeList class pass necessary prop to your component

```
class MovieTimeList extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `${navigation.state.params.theaterCn}`,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#81A3A7', 
      elevation: null,
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: '300',
      fontFamily: 'FFF Tusj',
      fontSize: 18
    },
    headerRight:
      <ModalSelector
        data={data}
        initValue={this.props.HeaderTitle}
        onChange={(option)=>{ alert(`${option.label} (${option.key}) nom nom nom`) }}
      />,
  });


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  let HeaderTitle = state.yourreducer.headerTitle
  return HeaderTitle
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(MovieTimeList)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Base on your code example, my `<ModalSelector />` still can't get the data from reducer.